# In how many ways can 6 children be divided into 3 pairs if the order of pairs does not matter?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

In how many ways can $6$ children be divided into $3$ pairs if the order of pairs does not matter?

In my book, the answer is only :

$$\frac{^6C_2\cdot^4C_2\cdot^2C_2}{3!}=\frac{1}{6}\cdot90=15$$

I do not understand why we divide it by $3!$ . What's the intuition behind this?

Comment: ${6\choose 2}$ are the number of pairs.  Once you pick a first pair on a list there are ${4\choose 2}$ pairs to put in the second position only a list and once you pick that there is ${2\choose 2}$ (0r $1$) pair to put in the last place on the list.  SO there are ${6\choose 2}{4\choose 2}{2\choose 2}$ ways to make a list of three pairs.  But the order of the list does not matter. So you divide it by the number of ways to order three items on a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause you are choosing an order in the groups. If i have the children as
$x_1x_2\dots x_6$ then if we pick $2$(by the $\binom{6}{2}$) we can color it with $\color{red}{red}$ for example
$$\color{red}{x_1}x_2\color{red}{x_3}x_4x_5x_6,$$ then we pick other two and color them with blue, for example
$$\color{red}{x_1}\color{blue}{x_2}\color{red}{x_3}x_4\color{blue}{x_5}x_6.$$ This is equivalent to $$\color{blue}{x_1}\color{red}{x_2}\color{blue}{x_3}x_4\color{red}{x_5}x_6$$ and any permutation of the $3$ colors. To avoid this you divide by the $3!$order of the colors.

Answer (score 0):

Was going through a similar question and found a visual aid that helped me picture the question. Imagine a 6x6 table, where it is labeled 1 thru 6 horizontally and vertically as such.

[image]

Next we pair them up:

[image]

Since we cannot pair two of the same person, hence, we will take out 11, 22, ... 66; which are the diagonal pairs highlighted in yellow

[image]

Lastly, we take out half the triangle which double counted AB, BA, etc... highlighted in green. This also interprets 2 ways (e.g.: AB or BA) of choosing. And yes this is pascals triangle. This visual aid is only applicable when there is equal distribution.

Mathematically; we start with 6 x 6 = 36, next we subtract the yellow highlighted pairs 36 - 6 = 30. Lastly we subtract the green highlighted pairs 30 - 15 = 15.

[image]